# DFT vs FFT: does odd number works for DFT only?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, dft

I am always confused between FFT and DFT. In both algorithm, it has been assumed that the signal is periodic (so my understanding is that, if you have a 20 sample point signal, and you do DFT or FFT, the algorithm assumes 20 sample points repeat).

Now here is the question, someone told me that DFT can take odd number of samples, and spectral leakage could be avoid if use DFT.

I disagree with the person because spectral leakage occurs in both FFT and DFT. And I also disagree because DFT and FFT can both take odd number of samples point, except that it would be slower in FFT case. Is this correct?

Comment: there are even FFT algorithms for length $N$ that are prime numbers.  at least i remember seeing some IEEE paper saying so.  certainly there are ways of decimating for $N=3^p$ or $N=5^p$.  and those are odd $N$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson [Bluestein's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform#Bluestein.27s_algorithm), which turns the FFT into a convolution of more conveniently-sized FFTs, so it's not exactly a prime-size FFT, but a multi-step process that accomplishes the same thing

Answer (score 6):

An FFT is an optimization for computing the DFT that works well for any number of samples that is the product of mostly small prime number factors.  They produce the exact same results, except for numerical noise. The factor 2 is common, but 3 and 5 are also small primes that can be used in a very efficient odd number length FFT implementation.  Many newer FFT libraries (Accelerate/vDSP, FFTW, etc.) thus support odd length FFTs, not just powers of 2.  On newer processors, the speed of an FFT is more limited by data cache size and policy and CPU instruction pipeline depth and hazards, not by the input being only a power-or-2 or not.

The algorithm makes no assumption about the signal being periodic (although some people do), as it is just a finite matrix basis transform.  If the signal input isn't exactly integer periodic in the FFT width, with that width being cut out of a longer signal, then there will be some windowing artifacts, often called spectral leakage (but they have the exact shape as the transform of the window used, so they are far more related to the window than to the spectrum.)

If you change the size of a DFT or FFT window so that it is an exact integer multiple of the period of a purely periodic input waveform, then the windowing artifacts (or leakage) just happens to be all zeros.

Comment: down arrowed due to mistaken second paragraph.

Comment: The Discrete Fourier Transform and the Discrete Fourier Series are exactly the same and have exactly the same mathematics. The DFT periodically extends the data passed to it. If the DFT results are $$ X[k] \quad \quad 0 \le k < N $$ the periodic function the DFT "assumes" is $$ x[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \ e^{j 2 \pi \frac{nk}{N}} $$ and that $x[n]$ is surely periodic:  $$x[n+N]=x[n] \quad \forall n$$. **ALL** theorems of the DFT are consistent with the periodic extension of the input and the **only** theorem that does not require this periodicity is the Linearity theorem.

Comment: just to be clear, the DFT and the DFS are exactly the same and have exactly the same mathematics.  but the DFS might have little hats on the input or output sequences, like $\hat{x}[n]$ an $\hat{X}[k]$ to indicate explicitly to the reader that the sequences are periodic.  as a result, in the theorems of the DFT/DFS that **do** require periodicity, the discrete functions with the little hats don't need the explicit language of periodic extension, using the $ \bmod $ulo operator such as $$\hat{x}[n] \triangleq x[n\,\bmod\,N]$$ or $$\hat{X}[k] \triangleq X[k\,\bmod\,N]$$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, DFT and DFS can't possibly be the same.  One is a transform, and the other is a series.  They're of different types.  What you probably meant to say is that the coefficients of the DFS are the same as the output of the DFT.

Comment: and on that note, there is no issue with the 2nd paragraph of the answer.  DFT takes $R^n$ to $R^n$.  Whether you want to assume that the output vector is a set of coefficients for DFS (and subsequently use it to extend the data), is up to the interpretation of the user.

Comment: last dissenting comment: any windowing artifacts are due to **windowing**.  windowing happens **before** the DFT (or iDFT or FFT, whatever) sees the data.  when you have a stream of data and you yank out $N$ adjacent samples out of that data set that is longer than $N$, you are windowing your data.  when yanking these $N$ samples out of your data, if you do nothing else to those $N$ samples before passing to the DFT, the particular window applied is the *"rectangular window"*, usually the kind of window we like the least.

Comment: @thang, what's not up to the user is the periodic extension that the DFT "interprets" the data having.  other than Linearity, the user cannot apply a single theorem that manipulates his/her data without running into this periodic extension.  and yes, the DFT and the DFS cannot possibly be different.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I am going to reiterate what I said.  DFT is a transform.  It's just a matrix multiplication by a specific matrix.  What is done with the result is up to the user.

Comment: @thang, the "specific matrix" has such properties that both the input vector and output vector of that matrix multiplication take on properties of periodicity if **any** theorems (other than Linearity) of the DFT are applied to one or the other of the input or output.  if the user does nothing to the result, the user will not see the periodicity.  if the user is **using** the DFT to do something non-trivial to the data, the periodicity is manifest.

Comment: Any assumption of periodic extension is incompatible with the common practice of overlapping FFT windows.  There usually is no discontinuity is the adjacent overlapping windows where assumptions would put it, thus making the assumption incompatible with the full corpus of STFT results.

Comment: have absolutely no idea what you're typing about @hotpaw2.  you can overlap FFT windows, and that says **nothing** about the periodicity.  but as soon as you try to **do** anything with your overlapped windows (like fast convolution) the inherent periodicity is unavoidable.  this is why overlap-add and overlap-save are necessary.

Comment: Yes, convolution via multiplication of transforms is circular.  But that is a separate or composite operation, not part of the bare FFT/DFT.

Comment: no, it is an operation covered by one (or more) theorems of the DFT.  rather than repeat myself, i'm gonna be lazy and refer to a [previous answer from me to another question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/about-discrete-fourier-transform-vs-discrete-fourier-series/18157?s=37|0.0514#18157).

Comment: The DFT "assumes" that the input is periodic. On the other hand, it is only a matrix multiplication, so from that perspective it doesn't matter if the signal actually is periodic or not. Still, to interpret the output of the DFT in a meaningful way, it is the discrete-time Fourier transform for an $N$-periodic signal. I would say that the second paragraph is if nothing else confusing and possibly misleading. Especially considering the number of questions here relating from the fact that people assume the DFT is the DTFT for any signal and do not understand the cyclic property.

Comment: And regarding "convolution via multiplication of transforms is circular". No! Convolution via multiplication of transforms must be zero-padded because the assumptions of the transform is that it works with a circular signal (not the implementation though, as it deals with one period). By padding one can make sure that it is possible to extract a part of the circular signal which contains samples that are not affected despite the transform being circular.

Answer (score 1):

DFT stands for Discrete Fourier Transform and FFT stands for Fast Fourier Transform.
FFT is just a name to refer to a very fast implementation of the DFT. So, basically they are the same thing. When using the FFT it is better that the length of the signal be a multiple of 2, for implementation reasons, so the it's usual to pad the signal with 0s until the length is a multiple of 2.

So, answering your question both "work" with signals of even or odd length.

Comment: Zero-padding to make the length a multiple of $2$ is the _wrong_ thing to do if one is interested in computing the DFT purely for the information that it conveys: the results obtained from the FFT _algorithm_ as the DFT of the _extended_ sequence are not the same as the DFT of the original _unextended_ sequence. On the other hand, the zero-padding works very well when one is not interested in the DFT _per se_ but only as an intermediate result while implementing a fast _linear_ convolution via $\text{FFT}^{-1}(\text{FFT}(x)\otimes\text{FFT}(y))$ where $\otimes$ is term-by-term multiplication.