# Can different Discrete-Time-Fourier-Series(DTFS) coefficients have the same discrete sequence in the time domain?

Tags: fourier, fourier-series, dtft

Please, check the following discrete periodic sequence when the period $N=2$.

$x[k]=\exp(j\frac{2\pi}{N}k),    N=\text{period}$

$..., x[0]= 1, x[1]= -1, x[2]= 1, x[3]= -1, ... , N=2$

According to my DTFS calculation, DTFS coefficient of above sequence is as follows.

$..., D_{0}=0, D_{1}=1, D_{2}=0, D_{3}=1, ... , N=2 $

If I shift above DTFS by 1 in the frequency domain like this,

$..., D_{0}=1, D_{1}=0, D_{2}=1, D_{3}=0, ...$

Inverse DTFS of above coefficient is as follows according to my calculation.

$..., x[0]=1, x[1]=1, x[2]=1, x[3]=1, ...    N=2$

Actually, if DTFS of $x[k]$ is $D_{n}$, then DFTS of $\exp(ja\frac{2\pi}{N}k)x[k]$

will be $D_{n-a}$ by DTFS frequency shifting definition.

So, DFTS of $\exp(j(-1)\frac{2\pi}{N}k)x[k]$ will be $D_{n+1}$.

In this case, $\exp(j(-1)\frac{2\pi}{2}k)x[k]$ is
$\exp(-j\frac{2\pi}{2}k)$ $\exp(j\frac{2\pi}{2}k)=1$.

Shifting by $-1$ shows the same result in this case because $N=2$.

So, I think above result is correct.

I know DTFS of $x[k]=1$ with $N=1$ is as follows.

$..., x[0]=1, x[1]=1, x[2]=1, x[3]=1, ...    N=1$

My conclusion is as follows.

$x[k]=..., 1, -1,  1, -1,...    \longleftrightarrow  D_{n}=..., 0, 1, 0, 1,...   N=2$  case 1

$x[k]=..., 1,  1,  1,  1,...    \longleftrightarrow  D_{n}=..., 1, 0, 1, 0,...   N=2$  case 2

$x[k]=..., 1,  1,  1,  1,...    \longleftrightarrow  D_{n}=..., 1, 1, 1, 1,...   N=1$  case 3

I can't understand the last 2 lines.
I think case 2 and case 3 should have

different sequences in the time domian.
What did I miss?

Comment: hay kappy, you need to learn how to use $\LaTeX$ math.  and you need to define what you mean by *"DTFS"*.

Comment: now what is the *"Discrete Time Fourier Series"*?  is that the same thing as the *"Discrete Fourier Series"*?

Comment: I think most people use the word "DTFS" instead of "DFS".  Please, check the chapter 11 and 12 of the following pdf file.  http://cfile24.uf.tistory.com/attach/173B49494EC1B160298290

  DTFS, DTFT, Z transform, DFT and FFT are not the same things.

Comment: Oppenheim and Schafer call the Discrete Fourier Series the "DFS" and it ***is*** precisely [the same thing that the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) is](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/about-discrete-fourier-transform-vs-discrete-fourier-series/18157#18157) but is not the same as the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT) nor the Z Transform.  *"DTFS"* is not a term I have ever seen in my 40+ years in electrical engineering and signal processing.

Comment: If you search the "DTFS" in the ieeexplore.ieee.org, you can find several papers about "DTFS". Please, check the following link. 

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=DTFS

Comment: For properties of DTFS, 
__1. http://pilot.cnxproject.org/content/collection/col10064/latest/module/m10784/latest

__2. https://pages.jh.edu/~signals/dtfsproperties2/indexdtfsprops2.htm

__3. http://web.mit.edu/6.02/www/s2012/handouts/tutprobs/dtfs.html

__4. http://dsp.cs.cmu.edu/notes/dtfs/dtfs.html

__5. https://pages.jh.edu/~signals/discretefourier/index.htm

__6. http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~ece2xx/ECE223/Slides/FourierPropertiesx4.pdf

__7.https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~aey/eecs451/lectures/dtfs.pdf

Comment: One more thing. There is s section about "DTFS" in Oppenheim's book. Please, check the 3.7 (Properties of Discrete-Time Fourier Series) of "Signal & Systems" 2nd Edition (Alan V. Oppenheim, Alan S. Willsky with S. Hamid Nawab).