# Are signals modeled either digitally or analogously or can signals modeled as both?

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, terminology

Are signals modeled either digitally or analogously or can signals modeled as both?

Answer (score 0):

Any signal can be modeled, but not necessarily *uniquely*. Any finite duration (i.e. real-world) signal is not bandlimited unless we assume it is - meaning, it has infinite valid representations.

This applies to both analog and digital. Specific cases:

1. **Signal is analog**: the analog representation is true by definition, but we still won't have a mathematical description (formula) for it unless we assume a bandlimit.
2. **Signal is digital**: the digital representation is true by definition, but we still won't have a formula unless we assume a bandlimit.
3. **We have a formula**: if its Fourier Transform is bandlimited, we can create a unique digital and analog representation. If not, then we require an infinitely long analog representation.
4. **We don't have a formula**: can't model uniquely either in analog or digital (i.e. can't convert), as in cases 1 and 2.

Note, when I say "representation", I mean the raw source rather than its measurements, as measurements are finite and cannot be analog/continuous. I also use "analog" and "continuous" interchangeably, and "digital" and "discrete". Lastly, a bandlimited signal is necessarily periodic (repeats infinitely and lasts forever).

If we don't care about uniqueness, then we can represent / make formula for anything in digital or analog. As for how we can assume a bandlimit, see [these posts](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/75088/50076).

Comment: Thanks, just a small thing, is "bandlimit" unique or very unique to signal processing? I just never came across it in English before.

Comment: @signalmodeler [Bandlimit](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bandlimiting) just means "finite range of frequencies", i.e. $F(\omega)=0$ outside of some range $[\omega_0, \omega_1]$. Due to how Fourier Transform works, the uniqueness statement is universal about (nearly) all functions rather than being just a signals thing.

Answer (score 0):

A common definition of a signal is ["a function that conveys information about a phenomenon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal).

By "modelled digitally" you probably mean a [discrete-time discrete-valued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_(signal_processing)) representation. By "modelled analogously" you probably mean a [continuous-time continuous-valued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_signal) representation.

If you mean that you would like to have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), then no, this is not possible for all arbitrary signals. For example it is not possible for random noise.

If alternatively by modelling digitally/analogously you mean, if it's possible to built digital or analog circuits to generate arbitrary signals, the answer is a clear no. A simple counterexample would be a signal that extends into the past, for which you would need a real [acausal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system), which is not possible. Another simple counterexample are signals with infinite energy.

As you can see, this question is far too broad and needs clarification to get any helpful results.